# Export Arabic data to Excel via VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

In my form, I have a ListView and I want to export its data to a file Excel. This is my code :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim csvFileContents As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim CurrLine As String = String.Empty
        'Write out the column names as headers for the csv file.       
        For columnIndex As Int32 = 0 To ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
            CurrLine &= (String.Format("{0};", ListView1.Columns(columnIndex).Text))
        Next
        'Remove trailing comma      
        csvFileContents.AppendLine(CurrLine.Substring(0, CurrLine.Length - 1))
        CurrLine = String.Empty       'Write out the data.  
        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            For Each subItem As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In item.SubItems
                CurrLine &= (String.Format("{0};", subItem.Text))
            Next
            'Remove trailing comma       
            csvFileContents.AppendLine(CurrLine.Substring(0, CurrLine.Length - 1))
            CurrLine = String.Empty
        Next
        'Create the file.    
        Dim Sys As New System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\Test.csv")
        Sys.WriteLine(csvFileContents.ToString)
        Sys.Flush()
        Sys.Dispose()

    End Sub
```

The code works fine, but when i open the file, the arabic data are not copied properly, this is how it look :

```
Ù†Ø¨ÙŠÙ„;Ø³ÙŠ Ø¹Ù
```

How can I resolve this issue ? Thank you

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @valter No, I used the encoding and the arabic appear properly but I have all data in one column in Excel.